# Replace string literal of unicode character with sed

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains the literal text `\u0275` and would like to replace it with the unicode character `ɵ`.

For example when viewing the UTF-8 file the line

```
"_\u0275DomRendererFactory2_21"
```

becomes

```
"_ɵDomRendererFactory2_21"
```

Attempting both `sed -i 's/\u0275/ɵ/g' bundle.js` and `sed -i 's/\\u0275/ɵ/g' bundle.js` results in `sed: 1: "bundle.js": undefined label 'undle.js'`

How does one search for the string literal `\u0275` using `sed` and replace it with `ɵ`

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. What OS are you on?

Comment: @melpomene Mac OSX 10.12.4